# Passing Date parameters into REST API call - Using R-

Tags: r, url-encoding, jsonlite

Trying to pull some data from a REST API however unable to correctly pass as date parameter into the string. Using sprintf I was successful in passing in the search term and website however no luck with the discoverDate.

https://newsriver.io is the API in question

```
Function to grab data by one search term and one website

get_newsriver_content <- function(searcht,website,api_key){
url <- sprintf('https://api.newsriver.io/v2/search?query=text%%3A%s%%20OR%%20website.domainName%%3A%s%%20OR%%20language%%3AEN&sortBy=_score&sortOrder=DESC&limit=100',searcht, website)
news_get<- GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = paste(api_key, sep = "")))
news_txt <- content(news_get, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8") 
news_df <- fromJSON(news_txt)
news_df$discoverDate <- as.Date(news_df$discoverDate)
news_df
}
```

Question Updated  - I would also like to make multiple API calls based on a vector of dates.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem here. If you look at the [query builder](https://console.newsriver.io/river/0), you can query by text, title, website name and language, not discoverDate (only available to sort the results). If I may suggest something else, talke a look at `urltools` package, in particular the `param_set` function. You can build your query in a much cleaner way:  `url_base %>% param_set("query", "...") %>% param_set("sortBy", "_score") %>% param_set("sortOrder", "DESC") %>% param_set("limit", "100")`

Comment: @quartin great advice I have also got the api creator to help me out the URL encode. I will post the answer shortly

Comment: @quartin updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I figured out my problem

It was really a 2 Step problem

1. Figuring out how to properly encode my query to be inserted into in the Curl Call
2. Creating a function that made an API call based on a vector of dates and appended it to a data frame.

Here is how I did it.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
library(urltools)
library(httr)

# Function For Pulling by Date  
get_newsriver_bydate <- function(query, date_v){

#Being Kind to the free API - Shout out to Elia at Newsriver who has been ever patient
pb$tick()$print()
Sys.sleep(sample(seq(0.5, 2.5, 0.5), 1))

#This is where is used the URL encode package as suggested by quartin
url_base <- "https://api.newsriver.io/v2/search"
create_curl_call <- url_base %>% 
param_set("query",url_encode(query)) %>% 
param_set("sortBy", "_score") %>% 
param_set("sortOrder", "DESC") %>% 
param_set("limit", "100") 

#I had most of this before however I changed my output to a tibble
#more versatile to work with 

get_curl <- GET(create_curl_call, add_headers(Authorization = paste(api_key, sep = "")))
curl_to_json <- content(get_curl, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
news_df <- fromJSON(curl_to_json, flatten = TRUE)
news_df$discoverDate <- as.Date(news_df$discoverDate)
as.tibble(news_df)
}

# Set Configration and Set API key
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
api_key <- "mykey"

#Set my vector of Dates
dates1 <- seq(as.Date("2017-09-01"), as.Date("2017-10-01"), by = "days")

#Set up my progress bar
pb <- progress_estimated(length(dates1))

#Sprintf my query into a vector of queries based on date
query <- sprintf('text:"Canada" AND text:"Rocks" AND language:EN AND discoverDate:[%s TO %s]',dates1, dates1)

 #Run the query and be patient
news_df <- map_df(query, get_newsriver_bydate, .id = "query")
```

So for my research method and how I came to solving these 2 problems

1. Quartin gave me a suggestion to look up urltools package https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/urltools/index.html - This package helps you encode and decode your URL and various other functions that are fast and vectorised. Next my issue was getting my query correct here I simply looked up the API documentation which I suggest anyone trying to pull from an API do. May sound like a no brainer but I didn't give it a full read before posting my question
2. Creating the function I used a number of previous answers to help build it however the below post helped the most

[API Query for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251565/api-query-for-loop)
This post helped me with the progress bar and the map function to get everything into one Data frame.

There may very well be a better answer but this works for me so far.